# Which validating python XML api to use?

Tags: python, xml, validation, dtd

I new to xml stuff, so I have no idea which api I should use in python.
Till now I used xmlproc, but I heard it is not developed any more.

I have basically only one requirement: I want to validate against a dtd that I can choose in my program. I can't thrust the doctype thing.

Performance does not really matter, so I would like to use the most easy api that exists.

What to use? Have you guys a simple example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my current project, I'm using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), which is fairly easy to use. Validation with DTD is described on [this page](http://codespeak.net/lxml/validation.html)